# How do I resize my Window twice with the same button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So if i try to resize my Window with the same button back and forth just the one on the bottom will work but it wont go back to '384x470' as if the Window wasnt '500x500'

````
def sizeWindow():
    if root.geometry('500x500'):
        root.geometry('384x470')

    else:
        root.geometry('500x500')
        buttonWinSize.configure(text="<<")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand several things here. Tkinter has relatively cool feature that allows you to use some methods for different things. Either you get or you set with the same method. To get you leave the interface empty (e.g. `root.geometry()`) or you set with the required argument (e.g. `root.geometry('500x500+0+0')`). You should be aware that you get the current value(s) in the same format as you set them.

Therefore you retrieve a geometry string by `root.geometry()` and this has the form of *width x height +x +y*.

However, not every time this feature is the right tool to achieve the overall goal. In your case you want to check for the width and height. Tkinter provides another feature for exactly this task. It lets you ask for the width and height via `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()`.

In addition you should know that every function in python needs to return something and if nothing is specified `None` is returned by this function. Since you use the setter variant of `root.geometry('500x500')` you receive `None` and `None` equals to `False` in python, therefore your `else` block will always be executed instead of your `if` block.

Suggested change:

```
def sizeWindow():
    if root.winfo_width() == 500 and root.winfo_height() == 500:
        root.geometry('384x470')
    else:
        root.geometry('500x500')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation im quite new to programing so that was quite helpfull!

Comment: @Liquid You are welcome. You find a lot of tkinter features on the site for [New Mexico Tech](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) and a lot of explainations here on [so] by [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley?tab=answers). Happy codeing!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if`-statement is wrong. You are actually setting the size with your first `root.geometry('500x500')`. This does (AFAIK) not return a boolean. So you need to check the actual current dimensions:

```py
if root.winfo_width() == 500 and root.winfo_height() == 500:
    root.geometry('384x470')
else:
    root.geometry('500x500')
    buttonWinSize.configure(text="<<")
```